# Identifique el caracter a evaluar OCR

Tags: matlab, ocr

Necesito evaluar si un caracter corresponde a una letra determinada, si asigno manualmente el caracter ha ser evaluado funciona correctamente pero si lo asigno a través de un input no funciona.

Necesito que cuando se digite la letra el programa la relacione y haga la asignación que le corresponde, en teoría esto debería funcionar:

```
w1=input('Seleccione una letra: ');
w=arr{w1};
```

Pero no hace la asignación de forma correcta, si se hace con el input siempre evalúa la letra a.

```
clc
clear all
a=imread('D:\DOCUMENTOS DELL\Desktop\ocr_vocales\a.bmp');
e=imread('D:\DOCUMENTOS DELL\Desktop\ocr_vocales\e.bmp');
i=imread('D:\DOCUMENTOS DELL\Desktop\ocr_vocales\i.bmp');
o=imread('D:\DOCUMENTOS DELL\Desktop\ocr_vocales\o.bmp');
u=imread('D:\DOCUMENTOS DELL\Desktop\ocr_vocales\u.bmp');
a1=imread('D:\DOCUMENTOS DELL\Desktop\ocr_vocales\a_arial.bmp');
i1=imresize(i,[7,8]);
a11=imresize(a1,[7,8]);
arr={a,e,i1,o,u};
arr2={a11,e};
arr1={'a','e','i','o','u'};
%w1=input('Seleccione una letra: ') % w1 no me almacena la matriz de bits de la vocal seleccionada

    w=e;  %Si la defino manualmente funciona
    %w=arr{w1};
    for s=1:length(arr) %filas
        m=arr{s};
        cont=0;
    for k=1:size(a,1)
        for j=1:size(a,2)
            if w(k,j)==0 && m(k,j)==0
                cont=cont+1;
            end
        end
    end
    conteo(1,s)=cont;
    end
    mayor=max(conteo);
    for k=1:length(arr)
        if conteo(k)==mayor
            disp('La letra es: ')
            disp(arr1{k});
            imshow(arr2{k});
            break
        end
    end
```

> Resultado de la ejecución

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Mis imágenes de las letras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Otro problema que se presenta es que cuando no hay coincidencia el conteo mayor siempre se está generando para la letra a y da como reultado que el caracter evaualado es una a.